# Rolling 4 different die...

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

My question is as follows:

I have four different die and I'm trying to figure out how many possible combinations there are of (6,6,6,3)

My intuition tells me that there are 24 combinations. I'm imagining we have 4 spots:

---

For the first spot there are 4 options (6,6,6,3)
For the second spot there are 3 options, etc.

I believe this is wrong but I can't figure out the flaw in my reasoning.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it depends on if you consider the repeats distinct.

Comment: It's four different die, so repeats are distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the 4 dice is the 3, and the others are a 6, so that gives you 4 options, rather than 24.

Where does your reasoning go wrong?  Well, the first die can be a 3 or a 6, so that is only 2  options, rather than 4. And if it is a 3 (Option 1) then all others are forced to be a 6, so there are no further options for that one. If it is a 6, then for the second die you again have 2 options (rather than 3): it's a 3 or a 6.  Again, if it is a 3 (Option 2) then the rest are 6's, so no further options there, but if it is a 6, then you have exactly two options left for the last two: 3rd one is 3 and 4th one is 6 (Option 3), or 3rd one is 6 and 4th one is 3 (Option 4).

So, two things went wrong with your reasoning: you counted too many options for the dice, and you also assumed that every option for one die would leave just as many options for the others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm intepreting your question as "I roll 4 distinguishable dice, how many ways can I get three $6$'s and one $3$. If this is wrong, please clarify what you mean.

The number of ways it just $4$. The moment one dice rolls a $3$, then the other die all have to roll a $6$. So each dice corresponds to just one way you can get three $6$'s and one $3$. There are four total dice that can roll a $3$, so the total number of ways this can happen is $4 \times 1 = 4$.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. Is there a formula I would use for this so that I can generalize to different cases.

Comment: Generally these types of questions are calculated using combinations. Read this [wikipage for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). If order matters you need to use [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). For simple cases like this they aren't needed, but for more complicated situations they make it very simple to calculate.